# How much can a plane benefit from another planes wake?

Tags: feature-identification, efficiency, turbulence, flying-in-formation

Could a smaller plane fly in a V formation behind a much larger plane to reduce fuel consumption significantly more than a plane its own size? At what point does flying in a larger planes wake become to turbulent or increased fuel efficiency stops?

[image]

Related: [How do planes benefit from flying in formation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16821/how-do-planes-benefit-from-flying-in-formation)

Comment: Dup of this post i think https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16821/how-do-planes-benefit-from-flying-in-formation

Comment: @JohnK Not a duplicate but it is highly related and added it to the body thanks.

Comment: The image you posted is of a fighter jet lining up behind a tanker aircraft for refueling. The fighter would want to AVOID the wake turbulence, since it is extremely dangerous to fly through.

Answer (score 4):

No, airplane wakes do not work like this. The streamlined body has very little wake, it is not like a cube shaped truck. The main wake on an airplane is found at the wingtips in the form of a strong vortex like horizontal tornado, aided somewhat by the down wash of the mid wingspan.

The tip vortex from a large plane will make a small plane spin like a windmill. A german bombardier challanger(mid size business jet) flew under an A380 at cruise altitude a few years ago and was turned over so hard the plane had to be sold for scrap, broke a one passanger's ribs, recorded near 4G force, lost 8000 ft of altitude before recovering control.

Comment: And then there are many cases where pilots weren't so lucky as to be able to regain control of the airplane before impact with the ground. [XC-VMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Mexico_City_Learjet_crash) comes to mind as a high-profile example.